# solve the initial value problem ,by Taylor's method of order $N=3$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

solve the initial value problem ,by Taylor's method of order $N=3$

$y'(t)=ty(t)+(1-t)e^t,0\le t\le 2,y(0)=1$

with an accuracy of $5 \times10^{-3}$

first we consider the taylor expansion of $e^x$

$ e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+....$

for $N=3$ we have

$\large e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6} \\ \large y'=yt+(1-t)(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{6}) $

bernoulli equation of the form $y'+py=q\implies y u=\int uq dx,u(x)=e^{\int p }dx$

$ y'+(-t)y=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{6}$

$u(t)=e^{\int {-t}}dt=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \\ y(t)e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}=\int (e^{\frac{t^2}{2}})(1-t)(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{6}) dt$

$y(t)= e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}\int(1-t)[ e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}+t e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}t^2e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}+\frac{1}{6}t^3e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}]dt\\=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}\int (e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}-\frac{1}{2}t^2e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}-\frac{1}{3}t^3e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}-\frac{1}{6}t^4e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}})dt$

$=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}\int (e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}})(1-\frac{1}{2}t^2-\frac{1}{3}t^3-\frac{1}{6}t^4)dt$

Comment: i am not sure about how to proceed to approaximate the solution of y,esp in evaluating the intergral

Comment: I know you are totally changed the question (http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/541313/revisions). Do you make sure you really want to ask $y'(t)=ty(t)+(1-e^t)$ or $y'(t)=ty(t)+(1-t)e^t$ ?

Comment: @Jonas12: Are you supposed to do this with numerical methods or using a Taylor expansion?

Comment: @doraemonpaul i made a mistake in typing at first...i thought no one saw the change,cos the question said,no views,the latter is correct . this is a course in numerical analysis first year but we dont have many tools so far,so i am limited...only i can use iteration or newton-rhapsody or any elementary tools

Comment: i edited the the error i made ,the integral $u=\int e^p dx$ is supposed to be evaluated as $e^{\int p dx}$

Comment: i jus studied fixed-point iteration,newton-rhapsod,newtns methos,aitkens process...thats all

Comment: do you know of any method that can deal with this problem completley

Comment: also i did the order of approaximation ${O}(n)$

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear, so lets use three methods to solve this.

We are given:

$$y'(t)=ty(t)+(1-t)e^t,0\le t\le 2,y(0)=1$$

**Method 1** Integrating Factor

We can solve this problem and get a result of:

$$y(t) = e^t$$

**Method 2** Taylor Series Method

To solve this using a Taylor series with $N = 3$, we assume a solution of the form:

$$\tag 1 \displaystyle y(t) = \frac{y(0)}{0!} + \frac{y'(0)}{1!}(t-0) + \frac{y''(0)}{2!}(t-0)^2 + \frac{y'''(0)}{3!}(t-0)^3 + \ldots$$

We have:

- $y'(t) = ty(t)+(1-t)e^t$
- $y''(t) = y + ty' -te^t$
- $y'''(t) = y' + y' + ty'' -e^t - te^t$

Now, we evaluate each of these at $t=0$, so we have:

- $y(0) = 1$
- $y'(0) = 1$
- $y''(0) = 1$
- $y'''(0) = 1$

Substituting these values back into $(1)$ yields:

$$\displaystyle y(t) =  1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \frac{t^3}{3!} + \ldots$$

What do you recognize this series as?

**Method 3** Numerical Solution using Taylor Series

Using a numerical approach for Taylor methods of order $n$ (in our case, $N = 3$), we have:

- $w_0 = \alpha$
- $w_{i+1} = w_i + h T^{(n)}(t_i,w_i)$ for each $i = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1$,
- where $T^{(n)}(t_i,w_i) = f(t_i,w_i) + \dfrac{h}{2}f'(t_i,w_i)+ \ldots + \dfrac{h^{n-1}}{n!}f^{(n-1)}(t_i,w_i)$

Can you now proceed with Method 3 (you have all the needed derivatives for this method from Method 2)?

Comment: You're on a roll today! +1

Comment: thank you Amzoti for the solution it really helped,i used it here https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=2F1A1E592AA23F47!494&authkey=!AMRcIiCWcTVuHBY&ithint=file%2c.pdf

Comment: @Jonas12: Very nice! Happy I could help and that you learned from it. When answers are helpful, you should upvote and/or accept them. Regards

Comment: thank you,it really helped a lot ,just got me started even thou i had no idea ___ thanks Amzoti

Comment: @Jonas12: I would recommend you compare the actual (closed-form) solution to the numerical solution as part of the exercise to see how close they are and to make sure there is not an error! Is that clear? Please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: i am currently trying to find the error,i am trying to do this and also get a visual simulation of the graphs error,specifically with matlab...there is an error in the approaximation...and the accuracy is said to must be $5\times 10^{-3}$ from the original question

Comment: how do you get $y_1,y_2$ ie in order to evaluate the error $|w_1-y_1|$ and $|w_2-y_2|$

Comment: You would compare the using the final closed form solution in both cases from the solution you found in Approach 1 (calculate the closed-form result at that value of $t$ and compare to each iteration of each iteration of the numerical approach). The Matlab error information is good too since that is what you are doing. You might even want to add those results to your write-up. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Attempt ${2}$

$y'+(-t)y=(1-t)e^t$

$u=e^{\int -tdt}=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$

$\large ye^{\frac{t^2}{2}}=\int e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}(1-t)e^tdt\implies ye^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}=\int e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}+t}(1-t)=\int e^{\frac{-t^2+2t}{2}}(1-t)dt$

$y e^{\frac{-t^2+2t}{2}} \approx \int(1+\frac{-t^2+2t}{2}+\frac{(\frac{-t^2+2t}{2})^2}{2!}+\frac{(\frac{-t^2+2t}{2})^3}{3!})(1-t)dt$

$let \\ x=\frac{-t^2+2t}{2},dx=(1-t)dt$

$ye^x\approx\int (1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6})dx\approx x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+c$

$y(0)=1,t=0 \implies x=0\\1(e^0)=0+c,c=1\\y\approx e^{-x}(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+1) $

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need to solve this ODE BY Taylor's method, since this ODE has close-form solution:

$y'=ty+(1−t)e^t$

$y'-ty=(1−t)e^t$

I.F. $=e^{\int-t~dt}=e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$

$\therefore\left(e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}y\right)'=(1−t)e^{t-\frac{t^2}{2}}$

$e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}y=\int(1−t)e^{t-\frac{t^2}{2}}~dt$

$e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}y=\int(1−t)e^{-\frac{t^2-2t}{2}}~dt$

$e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}y=\int(1−t)e^{-\frac{t^2-2t+1-1}{2}}~dt$

$e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}y=\int(1−t)e^{-\frac{(t-1)^2-1}{2}}~dt$

$e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}y=e^{-\frac{(t-1)^2-1}{2}}+C$

$e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}y=C+e^{t-\frac{t^2}{2}}$

$y=Ce^\frac{t^2}{2}+e^t$

$y(0)=1$ :

$C+1=1$

$C=0$

$\therefore y=e^t$